# How to make a defective recording from recordmydesktop playable

Tags: video, video-capture, video-processing

I try to record my precious skype sessions with my daughter thousands kilometers away. Sometimes it works, but the last time it sadly gave a segmentation fault and I lost the recording. Today, I booted my computer fresh just before the conversation and tried to record it. It apparently worked, but the file has some error and it cannot be played.

Please suggest a linux alternative to recordmydesktop. I am very sad. That moments in skype with my daughter are the best times in my lonely life now. I know it is necessary that volunteers put the programs to the test so that they help debugging them, but in this case I need something that works.

Additionally, I there is some way to play what is in the file I recorded today, I would be happy to try. This is the capture of the konsole during the recording:

> inma:~> recordmydesktop
>
> Initial recording window is set to:
>
> X:0   Y:0    Width:1366    Height:768
>
> Adjusted recording window is set to:
>
> X:6   Y:0    Width:1354    Height:768
>
> Your window manager appears to be KWin
>
> Initializing...
>
> Buffer size adjusted to 4096 from 4096 frames.
>
> Opened PCM device default
>
> Recording on device default is set to:
>
> 1 channels at 22050Hz
>
> Capturing!
>
> ^CShutting down.
>
> ---
>
> Cached 72482 MB, from 215345 MB that were received.
>
> Average cache compression ratio: 66.3 %
>
> ---
>
> Saved 54287 frames in a total of 54245 requests
>
> ....
>
> STATE:ENCODING
>
> Encoding started!
>
> This may take several minutes.
>
> Pressing Ctrl-C will cancel the procedure (resuming will not be
>   possible, but any portion of the video, which is already encoded won't
>   be deleted).
>
> Please wait...
>
> Output file: out.ogv
>
> [89%]   [Cache File 141]
>
> Encoding finished!
>
> Wait a moment please...
>
> Done.
>
> Written 921301705 bytes
>
> (885658169 of which were video data and 35643536 audio data)
>
> Cleanning up cache...
>
> Done!!!
>
> Goodbye!

But now I try to play the file:

> inma:~> mplayer out.ogv
>
> MPlayer svn r34540 (Ubuntu), built with gcc-4.6 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer
>   Team
>
> mplayer: could not connect to socket
>
> mplayer: No such file or directory
>
> Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote
>   control.
>
> Playing out.ogv.
>
> libavformat version 53.21.1 (external)
>
> Mismatching header version 53.19.0
>
> libavformat file format detected.
>
> [ogg @ 0x2b4a70f82940]Codec not found
>
> [ogg @ 0x2b4a70f82940]Codec not found
>
> LAVF_header: av_open_input_stream() failed
>
> Ogg : Warning found none bos page from unknown stream 1091944242
>
> libavformat file format detected.
>
> [ogg @ 0x2b4a70f82940]Codec not found
>
> [ogg @ 0x2b4a70f82940]Codec not found
>
> LAVF_header: av_open_input_stream() failed
>
> Exiting... (End of file)

What is happeing with this recording? Will I be able to repair the header or whatever is missing? How?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you do not have the necessary codec to play the video in mplayer.  You will need to find a codec that can decode it.  I can't tell from the posted information what codec it is.

Comment: But I can play the other recordings I made with identical circumstances yesterday... It is not a missing codec problem.

Comment: @Mephisto - I don't know why it worked the previous day or why it might have changed codecs, but the only critical error I can see in that log is that it can't find the Codec.